# Datastore callbacks are not called in Google Application Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, callback, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple GAE application using JPA  and eclipse plugin for GAE (sdk version 1.7.2).

I only have one simple entity mapped wit 2 properties : 1 Key  key ; and one String name.
I have created only one class (taken from the "Datastore Callbacks" documentation of gae)

```
public class PostPutCallbacks {
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PostPutCallbacks.class.getName());

 @PostPut
 public void collectSample(PutContext context) {

     logger.fine("Finished putting " + context.getCurrentElement().getKey());
 }
}
```

The database callback is not called.
I tried with several  other annotations (@PrePut @PreGet) but they still didn't work .
**I've  also  tried with the Datastore low leve API and the callback is still not called.**

I searched the web to see if there is a configuration besides the annotation processing jar manualy added for eclipse but I didn't find anything..
Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I jumped a little fast to stackoverflow..I had to restart eclipse and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide more information in this thread.  If you are unable to see the datastore callbacks being triggered.  Try this [procedure](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks#Using_Callbacks_With_Eclipse) as documented.  You need to do some simple project set up at Eclipse in order to make it work.  Hope this helps.